# JQuery can't get image width from tinymce on IE

Tags: jquery, image, tinymce

This problem only occurs on IE9. Firefox works fine, as do other browsers.

I am using TinyMCE (with the ImageManager plugin) on a textarea that the user uploads an image into. The textarea is dedicated solely to uploading an image. When the user uploads/inserts the image into the tinyMCE textarea and submits the page - I edit check the image dimensions to ensure it is the correct size before allowing the form submission to complete.

I load the html of the tinyMCE textarea into a JQuery object, then use jquery to call on the object's .attr("width") to make sure the image is the required width.

The problem is that on FireFox, it works fine, returning the image's width. On IE9, the jquery call to .attr("width") returns 0 (zero).

Here is the code:

```
sString = $('#projectimage1').html();   // fetch the contents of the tinymce form field
objWork.html(sString);      // load a work div with the html contents of the control
// check to see if the image has the correct dimensions
var objImage=null;
objImage = objWork.find("img:first");

alert("image html = " + objImage.html()); // this returns the correct html for the image tag, including the width
alert("image src = " + objImage.attr('src'));   // this returns the correct image src
alert("image width = " + objImage.attr("width"));   // this returns 0 in IE9!
```

The only thing I can think may be an issue, is when I "view source" on the image while it is being displayed in the tinyMCE textarea - all of the html used in the image tag is html encoded. So the '<' actually appears in the source as < and the quotes used in the width="219" property is actually set to width="219"

If this is indeed the problem, why does IE9 have a problem with this, but not FireFox?

If this is not the problem - does anyone have any ideas of how I might proceed/correct?

Thanks experts!

Answer (score 1):

Until the newly created image is actual rendered, the browser may not have finished loading the image from the cache and thus recorded it's width into the object.  Different browsers have different timing on when exactly they have finished loading something from the cache.  If you want the image's width, you should just get the width from the place that it is already loaded rather than the place you are copying it to:

```
var width = $('#projectimage1 img:first').width();
```

In either case, you will have to make sure that the image has finished loading before collecting its width.

Alternatively, you can check to see if the image has finished loading with the `.complete` property and, if not, then attach an onload handler so you can record its width when the load is complete.

If you want us to comment on what you see in View/Source, you'd have to give us a link to the actual web page so we can see what's really going on there.  Because you are getting other properties properly like `.src`, it seems unlikely that the browser isn't parsing the HTML.